# How to set the type of an element in a Fieldset child class in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, code-reuse, zend-form-element, zend-form-fieldset

I have two very similar `Fieldset`s `MyFooFieldset` and `MyBarFieldset`. In order to avoid code duplication, I created an `AbstractMyFieldset`, moved the whole code there, and want to handle the differences in the `init()` methods of the concrete classes:

**`AbstractMyFooFieldset`**

```
namespace My\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;
abstract class AbstractMyFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add(
            [
                'type' => 'multi_checkbox',
                'name' => 'my_field',
                'options' => [
                    'label_attributes' => [
                        'class' => '...'
                    ],
                    'value_options' => $this->getValueOptions()
                ]
            ]);
    }
    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return [...];
    }
    protected function getValueOptions()
    {
        ...
        return $valueOptions;
    }
}
```

**`MyFooServerFieldset`**

```
namespace My\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
class MyFooServerFieldset extends AbstractMyFieldset
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->get('my_field')->setType('radio'); // There is not method Element#setType(...)! How to do this?
        $this->get('my_field')->setAttribute('required', 'required'); // But this works.
    }
}
```

I want to set the `type` and some other configurations for the element, e.g. the `type` and the `required` attribute. Setting attributes seems to be OK, at least I can set the `required` attribute. But I cannot set the type -- the `Element#setType(...)` is not there.

**How to set the `type` of a `Zend\Form\Element`, after it has been [`add`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/Fieldset.php#L149)ed?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set the type of an element as each element has its own type and element class defined. In your `AbstractMyFieldset`, see the "Type" key within your `init()`. You tell the form to add the `MultiCheckbox` element class and want to change the class to another one. So you need to either remove the default and copy it's attributes and options over to a newly added Zend Form element.

Another option is to use the base `Zend\Form\Element` class you can overwrite the attributes and set the type attribute. `->setAttribute('type', 'my_type')` but ur missing all the benefits of the default Zend2 form classes. Especially as the default `InArray` validator for `Zend\Form\Element\Radio` or the `Zend\Form\Element\MultiCheckbox`.

Or you should just consider making an abstractFieldSet for the both fieldsets and define how they get their value options and reuse that. Like:

```php
abstract class AbstractFieldSet extends Fieldset {
    public function addMyField($isRadio = false)
    {
        $this->add([
            'type' => $isRadio ? 'radio' : 'multi_checkbox',
            'name' => 'my_field',
            'options' => [
                'value_options' => $this->getValueOptions()
            ]
        ]);
    }

    protected function getValueOptions()
    {
        // ..
        return $valueOptions
    }
}

class fieldSet1 extends AbstractFieldSet {
    public function init()
    {
        $this->addMyField(false);
    }
}

class fieldSet2 extends AbstractFieldSet {
    public function init()
    {
        $this->addMyField(true);
    }
}
```